# Viewport2DVisual3D blurry text on WPF controls

Tags: wpf, 3d

I'm attempting to host a WPF form on a Viewport2DVisual3D surface.  I've set up the camera so that the controls fit the width of the window.  The default geometry maps the entire form onto a square face, so it is necessary to do some sort of transformation to get the surface to look like a regular 2d form and not appear stretched vertically.  The form looks okay overall but the text doesn't scale well, it is blurry and blocky and looks bad in different ways from line to line.  Here's what I've tried to set the aspect ratio:

- A ScaleTransform3D
- Setting the mesh Positions to the proper aspect ratio
- Setting the TextureCoordinates to the proper aspect ratio

The first two get me the results that I want, except for the blocky/blurry text.  My conclusion at this point is that the font rendering is occurring before the form image is projected onto the 3d surface and then scaling occurs, so it will look bad no matter what.  Does anyone know a way to work around this or to set it up right from the beginning?  I don't know much about 3d graphics, just enough basic math to get the camera angles right, etc.

Have tested on Win 7 and XP.

Some of the resources I've used:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContentControl3D.aspx
- http://pavanpodila.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9C9E888164859398!151.entry

A few snippets of the code:

```
<Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
    <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="FrontFaceGeometry"                            
        Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
        TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" 
        TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
</Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
```

...

```
<Grid Width="500" x:Name="FrontFaceGrid">
```

Then in the Window_Loaded routine, e.g.

```
var aRatio = FrontFaceGrid.ActualHeight / FrontFaceGrid.ActualWidth;
FrontFaceGeometry.Positions[0] = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D(-1, aRatio, 0);
FrontFaceGeometry.Positions[1] = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D(-1, -aRatio, 0);
FrontFaceGeometry.Positions[2] = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D(1, -aRatio, 0);
FrontFaceGeometry.Positions[3] = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D(1, aRatio, 0);
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: did you try SnapsToDevicePixels="True"

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the blurred text and other visual distortions make the 3D XY aspect ratio equal to the 2D control aspect ratio. This is achieved by setting X and Y MeshGeometry3D.Positions. For example, a 2D control sized at 500x700 could be mapped to a rectangle 3D mesh without distortion by assigning positions

```
<Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
    <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="FrontFaceGeometry"                            
        Positions="-2.5,3.5,0 -2.5,-3.5,0 2.5,-3.5,0 2.5,3.5,0"
        TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" 
        TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
</Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
```

The image of the 2D control displayed within the 3D environment is always "stretched" to the mesh's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You will be rendering the WPF form onto a texture on the square and then displaying the square using the GPU's texture engine. Depending on the mode the texture engine is using this could cause blockiness or blurriness (since the texture engine will try to interpolate the texture by default).

Why do you want to render it using a 3D visual and not normally if it is intended to fill the screen?

Comment: I wanted to perform 3d transitions between two forms.  Specifically, my intent is to flip the form on the y-axis (assuming z-axis facing you) to reveal another form on the back.  The 3d stuff baked into WPF made this surprisingly easy at first blush, I'd just like it to look a little cleaner with the scaling.

Comment: Display the form normally, just using the 3D for the transition.